# windows, nvidia custom resolution to be default resolution

Tags: windows-7, command-line, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

There is a problem with nvidia drivers and reported monitor EDID: Monitors native resolution is 1920x1080 32bpp 60Hz, but for some reason it displays only portion of entire desktop (overscan/underscan) and image is blurry so I created custom resolution of 1920x1080 32bpp 59Hz CVT-reduced-bank that works fine.

The problem is when HDMI cable is connected windows automatically chooses wrong native resolution istead custom resolution. How can I set custom resolution to be default one ? So when computer boots up with HDMI monitor connected it will default to custom resolution.

Or is there command that I can execute to switch to custom resolution instead of using nvidia control panel ? In that case is there HDMI-connected-event that i can hook somehow to execute that command ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found control panel API here: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/common/src/NvCpl/docs/NVControlPanel_API.pdf. 
The following command is not working:

```
rundll32.exe NvCpl.dll,dtcfg setmode 2 1920 1080 32 59
```

[This](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/524072/rundll32-exe-nvcpl-dll-dtcfg-commands-doesn-39-t-work/) discussion reveals this approach is no longer supported :(

The solution is to make application that uses NvAPI_DISP_* functions to make appropriate changes.

```
- NvAPI_DISP_GetTiming() // with NV_TIMING_OVERRIDE_CVT_RB parameter set
- NvAPI_DISP_TryCustomDisplay()
- NvAPI_DISP_SaveCustomDisplay()
```

Only thing left is to run this program when HDMI is connected:
Here (missing reputation) is how to find device class GUID for the graphic adapters. Then use RegisterDeviceNotification() function to register for getting WM_DEVICECHANGE notification.